# How to get username from database in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm a beginner with Laravel. I'm trying to take out username by user `steam_id`.

I have table's called "`users`", "`match_players`" and "`matches`".

`users` table have a row called "`steam_id`" and "`username`".

`match_players` table have a row "`steam_id`" and "`match_id`".

`matches` table have a row called "`match_id`" as well.

I need to take out username by using `match_id` > `steam_id` > `username`

Example:

`users` table:

username: Paul | steam_id: 0:0:045658

`matches` table:

match_id: d54gwdG566G

`match_players` table:`

steam_id: 0:0:045658 | match_id: d54gwdG566G

I tried something like that:

*Controller:*

```
$match->CTplayers = DB::table('match_players')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->where('team', '=', 1)->get();
$match->CTplayersSTEAM = DB::table('match_players')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->first()->steam_id;
$match->CTplayersID = User::where('steam_id', '=', $match->CTplayersSTEAM)->first()->username;
```

*My view:*

```
@foreach ($match->Tplayers as $Tplayer)
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->name }} {{ $match->CTplayersID }}</td>
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->kills }}</td>
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->deaths }}</td>
@endforeach
```

I know the code is not very good, but I am just trying and learning.

### Edit

*Controller:*

```
            $match->CTplayers  = DB::table('match_players AS mp')
        ->leftJoin('users AS u', 'u.steam_id', '=', 'mp.steam_id')
        ->where('mp.match_id', '=', $match->match_id)
        ->where('team', '=', 1)
        ->select("mp.*", "u.username")
        ->get('');
```

Blade:

```
@foreach ($match->CTplayers as $CTplayer)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $CTplayer->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $CTplayer->kills }}</td>
        <td>{{ $CTplayer->deaths }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You should try joins.

Comment: You should try laravel relationships.

Comment: did you try creating Model and their relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Try Join:
I think this code should work, But i did not tested:

```
 $match->CTplayers  = DB::table('match_players AS mp')
                             ->leftJoin('users AS u', 'u.steam_id', '=', 'mp.steam_id')
                             ->where('mp.match_id', '=', $match->match_id)
                             ->select("mp.*", "u.username")
                             ->get();
```

In Your View u can get like:

```
@foreach ($match->Tplayers as $Tplayer)
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->username }} {{ $match->CTplayersID }}</td>
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->kills }}</td>
    <td>{{ $Tplayer->deaths }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Edited my first post. But still dont understand how to take out username? I edited by your code

Comment: Thank u! Understand now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try join,

```
$response = DB::table('match_players')
        ->join('users', 'users.steam_id', '=', 'match_players.steam_id')
        ->where('match_players.match_id', '=', $match->match_id)
        ->select('users.username')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model of match players table define the relationship.

```
public function username()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'steam_id', 'steam_id');
}
```

Then in your controller,

```
$players = DB::table('match_players')->where('match_id', '=', $match->match_id)->where('team', '=', 1)->get();

foreach($players as $value)
{ 
   echo $value->username->username;
}
```

Wil get you the username.